# CSS aligning bullet-points in different browsers

Tags: css

I'm trying to position a bullet-list. The idea is that each bullet-point will align with the letter above it.

The result I'm looking for is something like this:
-----* Word
-------* Another Word
---------* A third word

However, I have trouble making this look the same way in firefox and chrome. It seems that the bullet points are smaller than their equivalent in Firefox, and thus they are off by a pixel or two.

Is there a way to make this compatible cross-browsers using CSS?

Comment: all those `<li>` are siblings or they are nested in others `<ul>` ? could you provide the markup?

Comment: Fabrizio Calderan: They are nested in additional <ul>

Comment: see my answer updated :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/r9vkz/5/

1. I just set a padding left to `<ul>` element. Since they are nested the padding is propagated (you could also apply the padding left to the `<li>` element anyway, if you prefer)
2. I removed default bullet point, then I replaced it with the unicode `'BULLET' (U+2022)` applied to every `li:before` and it looks with the same size both in firefox and chrome (I also tried `'BLACK CIRCLE' U+25CF` but it don't seem to work properly)

Answer (score -1):

Browsers come with slightly different default CSS settings for things like bullets and headers. To solve this people often use a "css reset" - this is a bit of CSS that creates a common set of defaults.

I use the [Yahoo Reset 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). This will only solve half of your problem. This will make all the bullets in the browsers work the same way, but not the way YOU want them to look.

So use the CSS reset first, then add **your own** bullet CSS tweak.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that different browsers may use different images (of different size) for bullets.

You can specify the image used as bullet with CSS, to ensure it is the same on every browser:

```
UL LI.x  { list-style-image: url(x.png) }
```

Comment: Who voted down my answer? After all, this is the correct answer. The problem was different bullet sizes in different browsers, wasn't it?